# AJAX Request renders blank page

Tags: ruby, ajax

I am trying to get AJAX to work on my application and I feel as though I'm close to the finish line but the end result of what I have is not exactly how I want it.

I am following a chat tutorial which you can find [here](http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/gmail-like-chat-application-in-ruby-on-rails) but tweaking it a little to make it usable on any page of the application. How I have my chat functioning is;

1. Once a user is logged, a Chat button will appear on the navbar.
2. Upon clicking on Chat, a popup will slide out from the bottom right with a list of users and a Send Message button next to each users.
3. When the Send Message button is clicked, the popup of users will slide away and the chat conversation popup will show up with messages.

The problem I'm having is; when a user types in a message in the conversation, upon hitting the Enter, it gave me a:

```
Template is Missing
Missing template messages/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/gerardo/667-workspace/Term-H/app/views" * "/home/gerardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"
```

In the terminal, this is what happens:

```
Started POST "/conversations/1/messages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-03 19:04:01 -0800
Processing by MessagesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "message"=>{"body"=>"Video"}, "conversation_id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Conversation Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "conversations".* FROM "conversations" WHERE "conversations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("body", "conversation_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["body", "Video"], ["conversation_id", 1], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-12-04 03:04:01.087945"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-04 03:04:01.087945"]]
(4.8ms)  COMMIT
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 6.2ms)
```

I searched around StackOverflow and saw some recommend adding the code below to my create action in MessageController.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

After adding this, I get taken to a blank page and the URL on the browser is: http://localhost:3000/conversations/1/messages
and the terminal shows:

```
 Started POST "/conversations/1/messages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-03 19:21:24 -0800
 Processing by MessagesController#create as JS
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "message"=>{"body"=>"Please..."}, "conversation_id"=>"1"}
 User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 Conversation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "conversations".* FROM "conversations" WHERE "conversations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
 SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("body", "conversation_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["body", "Please..."], ["conversation_id", 1], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-12-04 03:21:24.358502"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-04 03:21:24.358502"]]
 (5.0ms)  COMMIT
 User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 Rendered messages/_message.html.erb (2.8ms)
 Rendered messages/create.js.erb (22.1ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 23.9ms | ActiveRecord: 6.9ms)
```

routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

      devise_for :users, :path_names => {:sign_in => "login"}, :controllers => {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}

      # Root Page
      root to: 'pages#home'

      #Video routes
      get 'video/index'

      get 'video/profile'

      #Pages routes
      get 'pages/home'

      get 'pages/subjects'

      get 'pages/profile'

      get 'pages/featured'

      #Suggestion routes
      resources :suggestions

      #Chat routes
      resources :users
      resources :conversations do
        resources :messages, defaults: {format: 'js'}
      end
    end
```

home.html.erb (After user clicks on Chat, otherwise hidden)

```
    <!-- Chat
    ==========================================-->
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <div class="chat-menu">

      <!-- Menu icon -->
      <a class="menu-close">Close</a>

      <!-- Menu -->
      <ul>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <li>
          <tr>
            <td><%= user.firstname %> <%= user.lastname %></td>
            <td>
              <%= link_to "Send Message", "#", class: "btn btn-success btn-xs start-conversation", "data-sid" => current_user.id, "data-rip" => user.id %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

JavaScript that controls the sliding in/out animation of div above

```
    $('#chat-toggle').click(function() {
      $('.chat-menu').animate( {
        right: '0px'
      }, 200);
    });

    $('.menu-close').click(function() {
      $('.chat-menu').animate( {
        right: '-285px'
      }, 200);
    });

    }
```

messages_controller.rb

```
    class MessagesController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate_user!

      def create
        @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
        @message = @conversation.messages.build(message_params)
        @message.user_id = current_user.id
        @message.save!

        @path = conversation_path(@conversation)

        respond_to do |format|
          format.js
        end
      end

      private

      def message_params
        params.require(:message).permit(:body)
      end

    end
```

If anything else is needed, please let me know. I can also provide visuals for the three steps above if needed as well.

Comment: are you returning a json response?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the only place where a JSON response is returned is in the Create action in the ConversationController. `render json: { conversation_id: @conversation.id }`